# out of memory error viewpager + imageView

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I am showing 100 images in viewpager, and my application crash ( out of memory error )  when i navigate between these images . I want to use destroyItem to free up memory but it is not worked. Can you help me ?

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {  
    return JpgFragment.newInstance(pos);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ViewPagerActivity.slidesSize;
}

public String getPageTitle(int pos) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
    Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying view at position " + position);
    View view = (View) o;
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
    view = null;
}
```

}

I set the ImageView in my fragment( in onCreateView )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well FragmentPagerAdapter will load all the fragments in memory at once. Consider using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, as this is efficient when you have to show a large number of fragments on screen at once.